# when I redirect my html page, my jquery mobile list does not update

Tags: c#, jquery-mobile, refresh

I have a list, and when I redirect my page, my jquery mobile list is not populating. It works when I refresh my browser though. Is there something I can add that would fix this jquery mobile issue?

Here's my code:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Reply", "Conversation", FormMethod.Post, new {data_ajax = "false"}))
{
     <span style="font-weight: normal; white-space: pre-wrap;">@post.Message</span>        
}
```

My post.Message object that I'm passing in is just a string that I'm displaying.

Comment: Please show us some code.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery mobile has some non standard behaviour when it comes to lists. I've had this issue myself and found that you need to manually refresh lists. e.g

```
$("ListToRefresh").selectmenu('refresh');
```